# Python/Numpy - Set Values within some Tolerance to the Value

Tags: python, numpy

If I have an array and I want to set values 'close' to some value as that value, what is the best way to do this?  I'm wondering if their is a numpy function for this.  If there is no numpy function, then is the code below the "best" (i.e. quickest/most efficient) way to do this?  It works for multi-dimensional arrays as well.

Code:

```
from numpy import array
tol = 1e-5

# Some array with values close to 0 and 1
t = array([1.0e-10, -1.0e-10, 1.0+1.0e-10, 1.0-1.0e-10, 5.0])
print t[0], t[1], t[2], t[3], t[4]

# Set values within 'tol' of zero to zero
t[abs(t) < tol] = 0.
print t[0], t[1], t[2], t[3], t[4]

# Set values within 'tol' of some value to that value
val = 1.
t[abs(t-val) < tol] = val
print t[0], t[1], t[2], t[3], t[4]
```

Comment: I think that's the best way of 'data cleansing'.  I asked a similar question on data cleansing a while ago, and your method is what was recommended.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339273/can-i-cleanse-a-numpy-array-without-a-loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not so quite clear what you are trying to achieve, but my interpretation is that [around](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html#numpy.around) is the solution for your case.

Comment: This is probably the closest to what I want.  However, it doesn't always do the exact same thing.  For example, with my code above, I could set all values in an array within the range of [val-tol,val+tol] to some value, without changing (i.e. rounding) any other values in the array.  Say I wanted to change all values in the interval [-3,3] to 0.0 without changing values outside the range of [-3,3], then around wouldn't work.  With that said, it does work for just small tolerances and will work for my current purpose.

Comment: @Scott B: You may want to work only with those elements fulfilling some conditions. For example L= (-3< t)& (t< 3), t[L]= around(t[L], ...). Thanks

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html

Comment: But this wouldn't round a value of +1.0e-8 to 0.0.  It would change a value of -1.0e-8 to 0.0 though (both of these using a clip of something similar to [0,1]).  However, I'm glad you pointed out this function as it will be useful for my task as well...